# How to Add device in google cloud registry using c#?

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform, google-developers-console, google-cloud-iam, google-cloud-iot

[image]Hello want to ask how to add device in google cloud registry using google cloud iot core with C#

i've tried the following code which is given on google console for adding device to registry but getting error of
"Google.Apis.Requests.Request Error The caller does not have permission [403]"

```
public static CloudIotService CreateAuthorizedClient()
{
    

GoogleCredential credential =
            GoogleCredential.GetApplicationDefaultAsync().Result;
        // Inject the Cloud IoT Core Service scope
        if (credential.IsCreateScopedRequired)
        {
            credential = credential.CreateScoped(new[]
            {
                CloudIotService.Scope.CloudPlatform // Used for IoT + PubSub + IAM
                //CloudIotService.Scope.Cloudiot // Can be used if not accessing Pub/Sub
            });
        }
        return new CloudIotService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            GZipEnabled = false
        });
    }

public static object CreateRsaDevice(string projectId, string cloudRegion, string registryId, string deviceId, string keyPath)
    {
        keyPath = @"E:\Downloads\thermostat-289211-bb93742bc12f.json";
        projectId= "thermostat - 289211";
        cloudRegion = "us-central1";
        registryId = "testregistry";
        deviceId = "C418B9962BC91";
        var cloudIot = CreateAuthorizedClient();
        var parent = $"projects/{projectId}/locations/{cloudRegion}/registries/{registryId}";

        try
        {
            //var credentials = GoogleCredential.FromFile(keyPath);
            //String keyText = File.ReadAllText(keyPath);
            Device body = new Device()
            {
                Id = deviceId
            };
            body.Credentials = new List<DeviceCredential>();
            body.Credentials.Add(new DeviceCredential()
            {
                PublicKey = new PublicKeyCredential()
                {
                    Key = "here i am entering my public key",
                    Format = "RSA_X509_PEM"
                },
            });

            var device = cloudIot.Projects.Locations.Registries.Devices.Create(body, parent).Execute();
            Console.WriteLine("Device created: ");
            Console.WriteLine($"{device.Id}");
            Console.WriteLine($"\tBlocked: {device.Blocked == true}");
            Console.WriteLine($"\tConfig version: {device.Config.Version}");
            Console.WriteLine($"\tName: {device.Name}");
            Console.WriteLine($"\tState:{device.State}");
        }
        catch (Google.GoogleApiException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            if (e.Error != null) return e.Error.Code;
            return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

attaching picture of roles on I am admin page highlighted with yellow is the current account i am using

Comment: Edit your question and show the IAM roles assigned to the service account.

Comment: Here is the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/samples/registry-management-samples#create_a_registry) shows you how to create a registry that you can then add devices to.

Comment: The current user might not have access to perform the requested action as described in the [document](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/status-codes#403_Forbidden), then confirm that the Service Account, has the permissions to perform that action.

Comment: I've given all the access of device control to my id also to service account but still not allowing me to add device however registries are creating successfully

Comment: Confirm that the IOT API is enabled on your project, following the instructions here https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/6158841?hl=en, then generate applications credentials here:https://pantheon.corp.google.com/projectselector2/identity/serviceaccounts?pli=1&supportedpurview=project, and pass them as environment variables

Comment: Do you want equivalent C# of [this](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/quickstart#add_a_device_to_the_registry)

Comment: @ErickSilverio IOT api is enabled how to pass these credential in environmental variables?

Comment: @Mahboob yes i want exactly this in C#

Answer (score 1):

See: https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/samples/device-manager-samples#iot-core-create-rs256-csharp

```sh
QUESTION="65413853"
PROJECT="dazwilkin-$(date +%y%m%d)-${QUESTION}"
REGION="us-central1"
REGISTRY="test"

BILLING=$(\
  gcloud alpha billing accounts list \
  --format="value(name)")

gcloud projects create ${PROJECT}
gcloud beta billing projects link ${PROJECT} \
--billing-account=${BILLING}

# Enable Cloud IOT
gcloud services enable cloudiot.googleapis.com \
--project=${PROJECT}

# Create Registry
gcloud iot registries create ${REGISTRY} \
--region=${REGION} \
--project=${PROJECT}

# Create Service Account with permissions for IoT
ROBOT="dellian"
EMAIL="${ROBOT}@${PROJECT}.iam.gserviceaccount.com"

gcloud iam service-accounts create ${ROBOT} \
--project=${PROJECT}

gcloud iam service-accounts keys create ./${ROBOT}.json \
--iam-account=${EMAIL}

gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding ${PROJECT} \
--member=serviceAccount:${EMAIL} \
--role=roles/cloudiot.provisioner

# Create RSA key
openssl req -x509 -nodes \
-newkey rsa:2048 \
-keyout rsa_private.pem \
-out rsa_cert.pem \
-subj /CN=cloudiot

docker run \
--interactive --tty \
--env=PROJECT=${PROJECT} \
--env=REGION=${REGION} \
--env=REGISTRY=${REGISTRY} \
--volume=${PWD}/app:/app \
--volume=${PWD}/${ROBOT}.json:/secrets/${ROBOT}.json \
--env=GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/secrets/${ROBOT}.json \
--workdir=/app mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 bash
```

Then:

With `app.csproj`:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Google.Apis.Auth" Version="1.49.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Google.Apis.CloudIot.v1" Version="1.49.0.2161" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

and:

```cs
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.CloudIot.v1;
using Google.Apis.CloudIot.v1.Data;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace IoTSample
{
    public class IoTExample
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args){

            string projectId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PROJECT");
            string region = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("REGION");
            string registryId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("REGISTRY");
            string deviceId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DEVICE");
            string keyPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("KEY");

            GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.GetApplicationDefaultAsync().Result;
            if (credential.IsCreateScopedRequired) {
                credential = credential.CreateScoped(new[]{
                    CloudIotService.Scope.CloudPlatform // Used for IoT + PubSub + IAM
                    //CloudIotService.Scope.Cloudiot // Can be used if not accessing Pub/Sub
                });
            }
            CloudIotService service = new CloudIotService(new BaseClientService.Initializer{
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                GZipEnabled = false
            });

            var parent = $"projects/{projectId}/locations/{region}/registries/{registryId}";
            var keyText = File.ReadAllText(keyPath);

            try
            {
                Device body = new Device()
                {
                    Id = deviceId
                };
                body.Credentials = new List<DeviceCredential>();
                body.Credentials.Add(new DeviceCredential()
                {
                    PublicKey = new PublicKeyCredential()
                    {
                        Key = keyText,
                        Format = "RSA_X509_PEM"
                    },
                });

                var device = service.Projects.Locations.Registries.Devices.Create(body, parent).Execute();
                Console.WriteLine("Device created: ");
                Console.WriteLine($"{device.Id}");
                Console.WriteLine($"\tBlocked: {device.Blocked == true}");
                Console.WriteLine($"\tConfig version: {device.Config.Version}");
                Console.WriteLine($"\tName: {device.Name}");
                Console.WriteLine($"\tState:{device.State}");
            }
            catch (Google.GoogleApiException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Your Cloud IoT registry (in this case `test`) must exist in the project.

See: https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/credentials/keys#generating_an_rsa_key_with_a_self-signed_x509_certificate

```sh
export DEVICE="device-01"
export KEY="rsa_cert.pem"

dotnet run
```

Yields:

```sh
Device created: 
test
    Blocked: False
    Config version: 1
    Name: projects/.../devices/2553842783141685
    State:
```

and:

```sh
gcloud iot devices list \
--registry=test \
--region=us-central1 \
--project=${PROJECT}

ID     NUM_ID            BLOCKED
test   2553842783141685
```

#### Update 2020-12-31

You may also create a device using the command-line. This would be a useful test to ensure that you've configured everything correctly:

```sh
DEVICE="test-02"
KEY="${PWD}/app/rsa_cert.pem"

gcloud iot devices create ${DEVICE} \
--registry=${REGISTRY} \
--public-key=path=${KEY},type=RSA-X509-PEM \
--region=${REGION} \
--project=${PROJECT}
```

Should yield:

```
Created device [${DEVICE}].
```

Comment: Can you please explain what are the steps i've written the same code and also dis the same as your comment but still getting the same error

Comment: Will add more detail to my answer